# antique dealer VS antiques dealer — Does "s" affect the meaning?

Tags: difference, singular-vs-plural, attributive-nouns

On [oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/dealer), first they give the collocation "*an antique dealer*" but then (in the "Extra Examples" section) give a sentence having "*an antique**s** dealer*" (with "-s"):
*She set up in business as an antique**s** dealer*.

Do "*antique dealer*" and "*antique**s** dealer*" mean the same?
If not, then what's the difference?

Comment: Perhaps it's a regional spelling and pronunciation difference. In the Americas, "antique dealer" is the norm. NGRAM shows that spelling ismore common: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=antique+dealer%2Cantiques+dealer&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Answer (score 0):

Normally we would say "antique dealer". "Antiques dealer" is just ... odd. Maybe in context they're trying to make some distinction. But probably it's just a mistake.

Similar for sellers of anything. We say "a car dealer", NOT "a cars dealer". A "shoe salesman", NOT a "shoes salesman". Etc. Presumably a shoe salesman sells more than one shoe in his career -- one would hope, anyway -- but we still use the singular. It's the type of thing he's selling.

Maybe, possibly, one would say "an antiques dealer" to avoid confusion whether it is a salesman who sells antiques or a very old, "antique", salesman. Like if I was tempted to say "a white paint salesman", meaning someone who sells white paint, I might hesitate that a reader would think I meant a white man who sells paint (of any color) and reword it.

Comment: Normally I would say 'antiques dealer'. Perhaps because an 'antique dealer' might be a poetic way of saying 'a very old dealer (of something)'. I suspect that's because I'm British, and I read the Antiques Trade Gazette: 'Antiques dealer and TV presenter Paul Martin is to open a new art and antiques gallery in the historic Cotswold market town of Corsham in February.'

Comment: @MichaelHarvey If I stress "antique", it's a dealer in antiques. If I stress "dealer", it's a dealer who is antiquated.